# Google Chrome browser show CSS attributes

Tags: google-chrome

(I found once found an answer for this question, but stupidly didn't bookmark it)

In chrome, when giving a name for a new css property, say `a`, chrome shows you all the css properties that start with `a` and similarly for other letters. What's the key board shortcut so that chrome shows all the properties available even when not giving a first letter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ctrl + space should show the full list of attributes.